# accessing members function of class in anonymous class out side package

Tags: java, package, anonymous-class

I have a class with data member in one package. Now writing the anonymous class of the class in another package.

```
package a;
public class A{
    String data;
    void print(){
       System.out.print(data);
    }
}
```

and in another package Now making the anonymous class of A.

```
    package B;
    import a;
    class B{
    public void static main(String[] args){
        A anoy = new A(){
            void print(){
                // overriding print
                System.out.print(data + " overrided");
          }
     }
    }
   }
```

Now here I am getting an error data is not public in class A. how to access data while writing the anonymous class without changing access specifier of data to the public.

Comment: That's not anonymous, that's package private

Comment: Why it is not able to access the data member of the class.

Comment: new A(){
            void print(){
                // overriding print
                System.out.print(data + " overrided");
          }
     }

is anonymous class

Comment: Make your class public. And why are you using this class like it's an interface?

Comment: You can't create an anonymous class out of a class, you create it out of an interface

Comment: Yes, you can. The above code works fine when you make data as public.

Comment: You are right. Sorry

Comment: So your problem is solved now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we declare/create an anonymous class in java. it is one new unknown(since compiler gives the name) class extends the class which you re-define (in our case it is class A). Acess modifier specified is default / package-private . Here the inheritance exists and the child class cannot access the private member of the parent. therefore it is not accessible.
In simple overridden print function will be in new class and String data member will be present in its parent class.
To access it should be converted into protected

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you have not overided the function. For overriding the correct syntax would be

```
package B;
import a;
class B{
public static void main(String[] args){
    A anoy = new A(){

        @Override // Now compiler will complain since print method is not visible.
        void print(){
            // overriding print
            System.out.print(data + " overrided");
      }
 }
}
```

}

When you are writing below code the anonymous class is creating a new method. Hence it is not complaining.

```
void print(){
    // overriding print
    System.out.print(data + " overrided");
```

}

You need to understand the mechanism of controlling Access to Members of a Class.

Access level modifiers determine whether other classes can use a particular field or invoke a particular method. There are two levels of access control:

```
At the top level—public, or package-private (no explicit modifier).
At the member level—public, private, protected, or package-private (no explicit modifier).
```

1. A class may be declared with the modifier public, in which case that class is visible to all classes everywhere. If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a later lesson.)
2. At the member level, you can also use the public modifier or no modifier (package-private) just as with top-level classes, and with the same meaning. For members, there are two additional access modifiers: private and protected. The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class. The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

The following table shows the access to members permitted by each modifier.

[image]

The first data column indicates whether the class itself has access to the member defined by the access level. As you can see, a class always has access to its own members. The second column indicates whether classes in the same package as the class (regardless of their parentage) have access to the member. The third column indicates whether subclasses of the class declared outside this package have access to the member. The fourth column indicates whether all classes have access to the member.

Access levels affect you in two ways. First, when you use classes that come from another source, such as the classes in the Java platform, access levels determine which members of those classes your own classes can use. Second, when you write a class, you need to decide what access level every member variable and every method in your class should have.

You can read further on :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

In your case your variable in package private.Hence, can not be accessed in different package. Hope this helps !

Comment: do you agree, the print function which is over rided is the function member of a class and member function can access any kind of variable regarded of access specifier i.e a member function can also access the private variable of its class.